# Digitalocean's wordpress one-click install stops continously

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, digital-ocean

I have a wordpress site hosted on a digitalocean's droplet and installed through their one-click installation that goes down very often. 
Here the url: sinc.marchespettacolo.it
Almost once a week i have to restart Apache from the console because the site is down and if i try to connect to it i get a timeout. 
I'm not that pro on making a diagnosis on what is causing this error.
Could someone help me how i have to proceed to find out what's causing this situation and how i can find a solution to the problem?
I have also another droplet with another droplet where i've installed wordpress with the same process that gives no problems!

Some says could be a problem connected to Apache opening to many processes.
This is the last process log, done while the site was down.

```
root@sinc:/# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  33460   980 ?        Ss   04:27   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:12 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        R    04:27   0:13 [rcuos/0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [migration/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [khelper]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [netns]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [writeback]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [bioset]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [kworker/u3:0]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [kblockd]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [khubd]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [md]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:05 [kworker/0:1]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        28  3.5  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27  18:14 [kswapd0]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   04:27   0:00 [ksmd]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   04:27   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [crypto]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [vballoon]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [deferwq]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [charger_manager]
root       116  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       118  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       119  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [kworker/0:2]
root       126  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 [jbd2/vda1-8]
root       127  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       313  0.0  0.0  19476     0 ?        S    04:27   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       323  0.0  0.0  51340   128 ?        Ss   04:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
message+   326  0.0  0.0  39228   268 ?        Ss   04:27   0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
root       392  0.0  0.0  43452   560 ?        Ss   04:27   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
syslog     396  0.0  0.0 255844   360 ?        Ssl  04:27   0:01 rsyslogd
root       430  0.0  0.0  15408     4 ?        S    04:27   0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
root       542  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [ttm_swap]
root       635  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:27   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
root       771  0.0  0.0  15656     4 ?        S    04:27   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       791  0.0  0.0  15820   116 tty4     Ss+  04:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       795  0.0  0.0  15820   116 tty5     Ss+  04:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       800  0.0  0.0  15820   116 tty2     Ss+  04:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       801  0.0  0.0  15820   116 tty3     Ss+  04:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       804  0.0  0.0  15820   116 tty6     Ss+  04:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       837  0.0  0.0  61364   272 ?        Ss   04:27   0:01 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       841  0.0  0.0   4368    96 ?        Ss   04:27   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
root       843  0.0  0.0  23656   204 ?        Ss   04:27   0:00 cron
daemon     844  0.0  0.0  19140    56 ?        Ss   04:27   0:00 atd
whoopsie   868  0.0  0.0 335684   792 ?        Ssl  04:27   0:00 whoopsie
mysql      916  0.1  2.5 918056 25668 ?        Ssl  04:27   1:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      1001  0.0  0.0  25344   376 ?        Ss   04:27   0:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
postfix   1006  0.0  0.0  27572   936 ?        S    04:27   0:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
root      1126  0.0  0.0  15820   116 tty1     Ss+  04:27   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1384  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:28   0:12 [kworker/u3:1]
root      1416  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:28   0:00 [kauditd]
root      2853  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    05:33   0:00 [kworker/u2:2]
root      3541  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    05:59   0:00 [kworker/u2:0]
postfix   6465  0.0  0.0  27408   968 ?        S    12:48   0:00 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
root      6508  0.0  0.0 105632   596 ?        Ss   12:58   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0    
root      6578  0.0  0.1  22404  1484 pts/0    Ss   12:58   0:00 -bash
root      6639  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    13:00   0:00 [kworker/u2:1]
root      6673  0.0  1.5 312976 15964 ?        Ss   13:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6677  1.8  2.6 319132 27180 ?        S    13:00   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6678  1.8  2.6 319132 27180 ?        S    13:00   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6679  2.0  3.8 324792 38892 ?        S    13:00   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6680  1.8  3.5 325320 35736 ?        S    13:00   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6681  1.8  2.6 319132 27180 ?        S    13:00   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6688  1.8  2.6 319132 27176 ?        S    13:00   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6690  1.8  2.4 317344 25372 ?        S    13:00   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  6691  1.7  2.6 319132 27176 ?        S    13:00   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      6700  0.0  0.1  18448  1292 pts/0    R+   13:03   0:00 ps aux
```

Any wonderfull idea?
Thaaaanks in advance.

UPDATE 
05-Apr-2016
here the Apache error log as requested:
https://gist.github.com/iperdiscount/ff06cf131f7ac1ec31aa28761e36b1c9#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: Hi! Anymore information you can give would help us answer your question. Are you seeing anything in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` ? You might also want to open a support ticket over on DO so the team can take a closer look.

Comment: When i try to access '/var/log/apache2/error.log' i got a '/var/log/apache2/error.log: Permission denied'. How can i avoid it?

Comment: ok i got im updating the question with the logs

Comment: here the Apache's error log: https://gist.github.com/iperdiscount/ff06cf131f7ac1ec31aa28761e36b1c9#file-gistfile1-txt